# Can't access a global Apex class inside a managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, package, global

I have an Apex class inside my managed package:

```
global class MyGlobalClass {
    global static void doWork() {
        //...
    }
}
```

But when I call this code from the org where this package is installed:

```
MyGlobalClass.doWork();
```

I get this error:

> Variable does not exist: MyGlobalClass

What can I do to make this class available not just inside the package, but also inside org where it's installed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to use the namespace to reference a component in a managed package. Just changing the code in the subscriber org should work. Here's the modified version you'd want to use (change packageNS as appropriate):

```
packageNS.MyGlobalClass.doWork();
```

Comment: Maybe add a footnote about [Setting Package Versions for Apex Classes and Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_version_settings_packages.htm). For packages with some history it may be necessary to set the package version to where the global method first existed.